# CKeditor SCAYT custom style

Tags: css, ckeditor

I want to customize the spelling error style in CKEDITOR 4's spell-check-as-you-type (SCAYT).  Specifically, I want to change the default red underlining to something more visually prominent.

Where/how can I customize the CSS of the underlined spelling error?

Answer (score 0):

Well misspelled words appear to be wrapped in class="scayt-misspell-word" as in:

```
<span class="scayt-misspell-word" data-scayt-word="humxans">humxans</span>
```

Perhaps you could use js to modify this class?

Comment: I was assuming there might be a CKEDITOR global configuration setting somewhere. I'll see what I can do with that class.